# Use of eof() in files in C++

Tags: c++, file

Can anybody explain how this while condition works while accessing files in C++. In the while condition, `employeeLine` is a string.

```
while ( !inFile.getline( employeeLine, MAX_LINE, ‘\n’ ).eof( ) )
{
    //some code here
}
```

If the file contains data like this then 
will the code process the last line data or not as there is no newline character

Tomb33bb9.75<\n>

bbMarybb26bb10.15
 (eof)

Comment: Use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and **don't** use `while (!eof())`.

Comment: @PrashantKumar: that's a good question, but it is for C and for `feof()`, not C++ and the `eof()` member function.  The arguments mostly apply, but they are differently nuanced.

Comment: To elaborate on 0x499602D2's comment - say `getline` reads a line and hits the end of the file (i.e. when the last line lacks a `'\n'`) - the loop condition you've posted would test `.eof()` and not process the line.  So, "how this while condition works": it doesn't.

Comment: @TonyD: That's wrong. EOF is only set _after_ an invalid read past EOF. **The loop condition is just fine**, if a little strange. It looks similar to invalid examples where the `getline` is performed inside the loop body, but it's not the same.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: if the last line has a `\n` then `eof()` won't be set - if it doesn't it will be set.  That's broken.

Answer (score 3):

First of, `inFile.getline(...)` return the stream, i.e., a reference to `inFile`. When the stream reaches the end of file, the flag `std::ios_base::eofbit` gets set and `inFile.eof()` returns `true`. While there is any input, this flag won't be set. If the last line is incomplete, i.e., is lacking a newline character, it won't be processed!

Note, however, that the end of file may not necessarily be reached: if something goes wrong, `std::ios_base::failbit` is set and the stream won't response to any further attempts to read something: you'd have an infinite loop. `std::istream::getline()` does set `std::ios_base::failbit` when the line is too long to fit into the buffer (i.e., there are more than `MAX_LINE - 1` characters). Another potential situation where the stream may go into failure mode without setting `std::ios_base::eofbit` is when an exception is thrown from the used stream buffer.

In general a better approach is to rely on the conversion to `bool` for a stream, i.e., to use

```
while (inFile.getline(employeeLine, MAX_LINE)) {
    // ...
}
```

There is no need to pass `'\n'` as last parameter as it is the default. There is also no harm.

Note, that the above code won't deal with lines longer than `MAX_LINE`. That may be intentional, e.g., to avoid a denial of service attack based on infinitely large lines. Typically, it is preferable to use `std::string`, however:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(inFile, line); ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your code is basically equivalent to the OP's code, is it not? I mean, it checks all the error flags instead of just EOF, but it's primarily the EOF flag we're interested in anyway... So you haven't effectively changed the program semantics.

Comment: The standard says _If the function extracts no characters, it calls setstate(failbit) (which may throw ios_base::failure (27.5.5.4))._ It does set the `failbit` if necessary.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the conversion to `bool` only checks `std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit` (27.5.5.4 [iostate.flags] paragraph 1 and 9). That is, it doesn't check `eof()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: but for reading strings, won't that will only happen at eof anyway, so it makes no difference to the loop termination....

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, you are right: for `std::istream::getline()` if the line would exceed the size of the buffer, it sets `std::ios_base::failbit` without setting `std::ios_base::eofbit`. That is, there is a genuine problem with the original code creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @TonyD: I think for `std::getline()` there is also a potential that the stream could go into failure mode (i.e., have `std::ios_base::failbit` or `std::ios_base::badbit` set) when an exception is thrown from the stream buffer.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: for corrupt files, network failures/disconnects etc. yes... makes sense.  Cheers.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl: If the file contains data like this then will the code process the last line data or not as there is no newline character

Tomb33bb9.75<\n>

bbMarybb26bb10.15 (eof)

Comment: @RaviKasaudhan: yes: as long as there is data being read, the stream will succeed. If you don't want to process the last line because you only want to process complete lines, you could check if `inFile.eof()` is set: if it is there was no newline because the stream needed to hit EOF to stop. If there is a newline, even if it is the last character in the stream, `inFile.eof()` will not be set.

Answer (score 0):

If  "`inFile.getline( employeeLine, MAX_LINE, ‘\n’ ).eof( )`" returns TRUE, it means that we reach the end of "inFile". So "`!inFile.getline( employeeLine, MAX_LINE, ‘\n’ ).eof( )`" means that we do not reach the end of "inFile".

See details in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykfk8bc0.aspx)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Can you explain whether getline reads the line until a newline appears and then checks for eof() or something else goes there.

Comment: I doubt if what the standard says fits in one comment, but...§27.7.2.3 says: _Effects: Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1). After
constructing a sentry object, extracts characters and stores them into successive locations of an array
whose first element is designated by s. Characters are extracted and stored until one of the following
occurs:
/ 1. end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function calls `setstate(eofbit));`_ […continued…]

Comment: […continuation…]
_/ 2. `traits::eq(c, delim)` for the next available input character `c` (in which case the input character is extracted but not stored);
/ 3. `n` is less than one or `n-1` characters are stored (in which case the function calls `setstate(failbit)`).
/ These conditions are tested in the order shown.
/ If the function extracts no characters, it calls `setstate(failbit)` (which may throw `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4)).
/ In any case, if `n` is greater than zero, it then stores a null character (using `charT()`) into the next
successive location of the array.
/ Returns: `*this`._